# Get count of a given item inside a list (without using numpy)

Tags: python, list, numpy, frequency

I'm trying to figure out how to count the frequency of each unique number in the below array, ranging from 1 - 17:

```
x3 = [ 8 12 10  9  6  6  5 11  9 10  4 12 10  7  7  7  7  9  8  7  9  6  7  8
  8 10  7  9  9  5  9  7  5 12 12 10  7  6  9  8  6  8  5 11  7  9  7  9
  9  7 12 10 12 11  9 11  6  7  5  8  8  7 10  8  7  9  6 10  6 13]
```

Using numpy, this was done by `[np.equal(x3, i).sum() for i in range (1,18)]`

What is the best alternative way to do this without numpy?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: collections.Counter works... if that was a valid python list of course.

Comment: IMHO, `np.unique(x3)`, `np.hist(x3, bins=np.arange(1,18)`, `np.bincount(x3)` are all better options, albeit with numpy.

Comment: You can also use normal ```dictionary```. If a value does not exists, put that number as key, put 1 as value. If a value exists, then add +1 to the value.

Answer (score 3):

The standard collections module can do it

```
import collections
x3 = [1,1,2,2]
counts = collections.Counter(x3)
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a dictionary

```
numList = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,2]
freq = dict()
for num in numList:
    if num in freq.keys():
        freq[num] += 1
    else:
        freq[num] = 1

print(freq)
{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1}
```